# Updating ESXi isn't updating the image profile

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm attempting to update my ESXi server (free installation) and I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. I've been reading up on how to use the `esxcli software profile update` command to get updates, but after applying the profile my system still shows the old image profile version.

I'm using the links to the image profiles from here: https://esxi-patches.v-front.de/ESXi-6.0.0.html

Each image profile has a nice link to the command string needed to update the host system, but mine isn't changing.

I've attempted to install the image profile for version `ESXi-6.0.0-20161004001-standard (Build 4510822)` but as you can see from the output, It's still showing the old image profile `ESXi-6.0.0-20160302001-standard`.

```
[root@esxi:~] esxcli software profile get
(Updated) ESXi-6.0.0-20160302001-standard
   Name: (Updated) ESXi-6.0.0-20160302001-standard
   Vendor: esxi
   Creation Time: 2016-10-23T15:40:42
   Modification Time: 2016-10-23T15:41:19
   Stateless Ready: True
   Description: 

      (Original Vendor):VMware, Inc.
      2016-10-23T15:40:41.852191+00:00: The following VIBs are
      installed:
        vsan  6.0.0-2.46.4510300
        esx-ui        1.4.0-3959074
        vsanhealth    6.0.0-3000000.3.0.2.46.4510825
        net-vmxnet3   1.1.3.0-3vmw.600.2.43.4192238
        misc-drivers  6.0.0-2.43.4192238
        esx-base      6.0.0-2.46.4510822
        tools-light   6.0.0-2.43.4192238
      ----------
      (Original Vendor):VMware, Inc.
      2016-10-08T20:54:16.010318+00:00: The following VIBs are
      installed:
        char-hpilo    550.9.0.0.9-1OEM.550.0.0.1198611
        hpssacli      1.50.4.0-5.5.0.1198611
        hponcfg       5.5.0.04-00.11.13.1198611
        hptestevent   5.5.0.01-00.00.6.1198611
        hpbootcfg     5.5.0.01-01.02.10.1198611
      ----------
      For more information, see http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2142190.
```

When I first ran it, it had a few updated VIBS, but mostly nothing changed. New tries are showing 0 changes to the system.

```
[root@esxi:~] esxcli software profile update -p ESXi-6.0.0-20161004001-standard -d https://hostu
pdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/PRODUCTION/main/vmw-depot-index.xml --dry-run
Update Result
   Message: Dryrun only, host not changed. The following installers will be applied: []
   Reboot Required: false
   VIBs Installed: 
   VIBs Removed: 
   VIBs Skipped: [All of them]
```

Is this as simple as me running a free ESXi license? Or is something else the cause?

Comment: Are you specifically referring to the name of the profile or are the versions of installed components not upgraded?

Comment: I'm assuming that the name of the install profile should update along with the components when applying an update. I'm not familiar enough with this level of management of ESXi to know what to expect. I can assume the components are updated, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is normal behavior. The name of the installed Imageprofile has indeed changed, from "ESXi-6.0.0-20160302001-standard" to "(Updated) ESXi-6.0.0-20160302001-standard". This is expected when you use the "esxcli software profile update" command. If it was "(Updated) ..." before already then it would even not change at all.

However, in the "Description" tag of the installed imageprofile you see the complete history of changes that were done to the system, e.g. with the latest successful update at "2016-10-23T15:40:41.852191+00:00".

Only if you re-install ESXi with an Imageprofile (from the VMware Online Depot or an Offline Bundle) the installed Imageprofile will have the name of the one that was actually used for the installation.

Comment: Hm. Ok. So let's so another update comes out, how do I know which one I should apply (yes, I know the "latest")? How do I know if I've already applied a previous image profile? It seems like the updates shown are specific to the actual items themselves.

Comment: I would use the version number of the esx-base VIB (the last part of it is also referenced to and displayed as the "ESXi build number") as a reference and compare that to the patch bundles listed at https://esxi-patches.v-front.de.